# call and control git bash from python script in windows

Tags: python, windows, git, pexpect

please assist, if possible, on the issue I am facing. (have done extensive search, many suggestions seemed promising, but have not managed to get quite where I wanted).

I am working in windows (7 -64 bit) and would like to devise a python script that would automatically pull from git (and later perform other actions).
Problem is that, git repositories in our company are designed in such a way that, when opening git-bash, we use a special 'assisting' function (git_help_fn) that allows to switch between repos, pull them and merge them automatically. This means that I cannot use the built-in python git commands. 
What I do manually is :

```
git_help_fn -r1 % in order to move to r1 repo
git pull
git_help_fn -r2 % in order to move to r2 repo
git pull
```

So, what I am looking after is a way of calling git-bash from python and interacting with it, providing predefined commands (like the above ones) and, at the beginning at least, hard-coded password (just to see it works).

After a lot of searching and tests with python subprocess and stdin/stdout write/read attempts I concluded that module winexpect is what I need.

However, the furthest I have gone is by using:

```
child = winspawn(os.system('start "" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe" --login'))
```

This way, git bash opens, I can type by hand, but cannot pass any commands through python. Python returns error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\winpexpect.py", line 346, in __init__
logfile=logfile, cwd=cwd, env=env)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\pexpect.py", line 429, in __init__
self._spawn (command, args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\winpexpect.py", line 362, in _spawn
args = split_command_line(command)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\winpexpect.py", line 78, in split_command_line
for c in itertools.chain(cmdline, ['EOI']):  # Mark End of Input
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I imagine that, what I am trying to do is not something overly complicated. However, I am not an experienced programmer and have reached a dead-end. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Thanos

Comment: Why don't you call the python script from the git bash? Or even create a simple bash script to run on git bash?

Comment: @  danielfranca. Thanks for the response. There are also other tasks to be performed by the python script so I would like it to be the father process and to call git_bash as a child.

Comment: I think the windows prompt is very limited regarding this kind of stuff.
Split your solutions would be a problem?

Comment: @ danielfranca. Sorry, I am not sure why you refer to the windows prompt. I am looking for a solution in a single Python script. Sorry if I you are trying to make a point I am not getting...